# Do I Have Two kernels Running at the same time?

Tags: kernel

I was Looking into a Random reboot problem (probably bad cooling), and stumbled into this:

```
luctins@lucas-PC:~$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-39-generic Wed Mar  1 21:19   still running
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-39-generic Wed Mar  1 16:44   still running

wtmp begins Wed Mar  1 16:44:10 2017
```

Does this means i'm running two OS's at the same time?
On Ubuntu 16.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. From the man page: "last reboot will show a log of all the reboots since the log  file  was created." Every time you reboot, you'll get another entry there (and when the log file rotates, they'll all go away). You're only running one OS at a time, though.